# how can i get the average of list in java with no loop

Tags: java

```
public static float myAverage(List<Float> elems){
    return /* Answer with no loop */; 
}
```

how can i get the average of List in one line;
no extra library like apache, no loop
please help me

i can not make another methods and classes.

-----Original---

```
//The answer must have balanced parentesis, and not containing "exerciseAverage"
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise{
public static float myAverage(List<Float> elems){[???]}
//compute the average, 0f on empty lists
public static float exerciseAverage(List<Float> elems){
    /*omitted*/
    /*omitted*/
/*omitted*/
}
public static void main(String [] arg){
List<List<Float>> tests=Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(1f,2f,3f,4f,5f,6f,7f),
    Arrays.asList(-1f,-2f,-3f,-7f,-13f),
    Arrays.asList(-0.5f,0f,0f,0f,30f,-100f,200f,23f,42f),
    Arrays.asList(-12f/3f,32f,12f,45f,-1000f,99f),
    Arrays.asList(-13f/0f,-100f/0f),
    Arrays.asList(7f,6f,4f,3f,2f,1f,0f,-100f),
    Arrays.asList(7f,6f,4f,3f,2f,1f,0f,1f,2f,3f,4f,5f,6f,7f,8f)
    );
    for(List<Float> ls:tests)
assert myAverage(ls)==exerciseAverage(ls): "error on"+ls+" "+myAverage(ls)+" " +exerciseAverage(ls);
    }
}
```

--- i found!

```
return (elems.size() == 0 ) ? 0 : (myAverage(elems.subList(0, elems.size()-1) ) * (elems.size()-1) + elems.get(elems.size()-1))/(float)elems.size();
```

Comment: What's wrong with loops?

Comment: @helb it's oneline-quiz

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt can you let me know a way with java 8 ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Recursion cannot be done with a single expression. You need at least one if statement in addition to the recursion call.

Comment: We can do it using size() and if else function, But it will take more execution time compare to loop and also LOC will increase.

Comment: @helb: I'm pretty sure this could be achieved with `?:`...

Comment: I don't think this can be done with recursion because it requires division of the sum by the starting size of the list.

Comment: @Radiodef: No it doesn't.  If `avg[n]` is the average of the first `n` elements, then `avg[n] = ((n-1)*avg[n-1] + x[n-1])/n`.

Comment: @user3483350 JB Nizet beat me to it

Comment: return (elems.size() == 0 ) ? 0 : (myAverage(elems.subList(0, elems.size()-1) ) * ((float)(elems.size()-1)) + elems.get(elems.size()-1))/(float)elems.size();

Comment: You should ask these kind of questions at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8:

```
return elems.stream().reduce(0F, Float::sum) / elems.size();
```

Or

```
return (float) elems.stream().mapToDouble(Float::doubleValue).average().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion:

```
public static float myAverage(List<Float> elems){
    final int N = elems.size();  // For brevity, inline if you wish
    return (N == 0) ? 0 : (myAverage(elems.subList(1,N)) * (N-1) + elems.get(0)) / N;
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/V7OVT3.

However, note that this will suffer from serious numerical problems; you shouldn't use this for real mathematical work.